# How to obtain file name from the path of the file stored in the distributed cache of HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, filenames

```
public void configure(JobConf job) {
        inputFile = job.get("map.input.file");
            Path[] cacheFiles = new Path[2];
              try {
                  Path file0 = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job)[0];
                  Path file1 = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job)[1];
              } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.err.println("Caught exception while getting cached files: " + StringUtils.stringifyException(ioe)); 
           }
     }
```

I am writing the code in the configure function.

Now how do I get the file names from the Paths file0 and file1? I need the file names because I need to store the data from both the files into two separate Hashmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
Path file0 = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job)[0];
Path file1 = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job)[1];
String filename0 = file0.getName();
String filename1 = file1.getName();
```